# How can I determine significance of the presence of one variable on a binary dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to know if the presence of one variable significantly determines the dependent variable (which is binary ie. can only be 0 or 1). Is there any statistical analysis, other than computing a correlation, that I can perform to determine any statistical significance?

While I cannot disclose details of my research, I will give an example: If I go and knock on someone's door to campaign, the person can either reject or accept my campaign. So I would like to know how significant the presence of me knocking on someone's door to campaign is in influencing their decision to accept as opposed to maybe they endorse the campaign on their own.

Hopefully that makes sense!

EDIT: I will have 3 or 4 predictor variables, all of which are categorical with 3+ levels.

Comment: Are you only ever going to have one predictor variable or perhaps several? Is your predictor itself binary, categorical with three or more levels, continuous? Best to edit your question to keep all the information together.

Comment: I just added an edit to answer your comment @mdewey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for logistic regression or probit regression. They are almost identical but each is favoured in different areas of science, for instance in my experience in health logistic is almost universal while economists tend to use probit. Both of them are available in standard software.